# Error in this wordpress loop

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone try this code?
It seems there are some errors in lines 25 and 44. Is is in home.php, and it reminds me just an empty page on the browser.
I dont know PHP so I cannota find what is the problem, can you hel me with it ?

```
<?php 
if (is_front_page() ) {
       get_header( 'front' );

} else {
       get_header();
}
?>

<section id="content" class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
 if ( $wp_query->current_post === 0 ) { ?>
    <article class="thumbnail thumbnail-principale expand-image">
        <div class="featured-image">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php    the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="destacado"><h3>Destacado</h3></div>
            <header class="testo-articolo">
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
                </div>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                <?php comments_template(); ?><!-- da sistemare -->
            </header>
    </article>
</div>

<?php

} elseif ( $wp_query->current_post >= 1 && $wp_query->current post <= 2 ) { ?>

<div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
    <article class="thumbnail thumbnail-destra expand-image">
        <div class="featured-image">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
        </div>
        <header class="testo-articolo-destra expand-image">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('0', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
            </div>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </header>
        <div class="badge1"></div>
    </article>
</div>
<?php 

} elseif ( $wp_query->current_post >= 3 ) { ?>

<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <article class="thumbnail distanza expand-image">
        <div class="featured-image">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array('class' => 'img-responsive ingrandire-img')); ?></a>
        </div>
        <header class="testo-articolo">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="entry-meta">
                <p class="text-muted resume"><span><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><?php the_time('j M y'); ?></span><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><?php the_author(); ?></span><span><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i><?php comments_popup_link('Ningún comentario', '1 Comentario', '% Comentarios'); ?></span></p>
            </div>
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lee más', 'katartika' ); ?></a></p>
        </header>
    </article>
</div>

<?php }

endwhile; 
endif; ?>


</div><!-- /row -->
<div style="text-align:center;">
<?php posts_nav_link(‘|’, ‘Prossimo’, ‘Precedente’); ?>
</div>
</section>
</div><!-- /sezione -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: did you enable [debug](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple php errors. Fix them as bellow.
Line No 34
Use this code

```
} elseif ( $wp_query->current_post >= 1 && $wp_query->current_post <= 2 ) { ?>
```

Line No 79
Use this code

```
<?php posts_nav_link('|', 'Prossimo', 'Precedente'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!
Can you help me with pagination, or I have to ask a new question?

Comment: I need a different layout from page two onwards, I would like it to show 6 posts, exactly like last 6 posts in the first page (wich is the page with the code shown above).